# How to switch off the syntax checker in YouCompleteMe?

Tags: vim

YouCompleteMe has an added syntax checker that comes along with it. How can I switch it off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the following in your vimrc

```
let g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui = 0
```

To learn more about this option read `:h g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui`

Comment: The syntax checker switched off but so has the autocomplete.